# Как указать xmlns у класса без namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть класс без `namespace`, потребовалось достучаться до него из xaml.

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:?????"/>
```

Что писать в `xmlns:local` чтобы достучатся до класса без `namespace`

Comment: А хороший вопрос, кстати!

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так:

```
<Window x:Class="GlobalNamespaceWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Intellisense ругается на `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"`, но проект компилируется и запускается без проблем.

Однако, я не смог таким образом сослаться на контрол из корневого namespace в *другой* сборке.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но хотелось бы без варнингов =)